# How to search for granted German patents, and not published German patent applications?

Tags: search, germany

I would like to find all granted German patents owned by a certain company. When I ran a Basic Search on [depatisnet](https://www.dpma.de/english/patents/search/index.html), the returned results were all published patent *applications* in Germany, but not *granted* German patents. Any suggestions on how to refine the search to get only granted patents? It's fine to include expired patents as well as active patents.

Comment: Based on past answers, I just found [Lens](https://www.lens.org) and you can search by patent type, such as granted patents, and jurisdictions, such as Germany. In the Analysis tab, there are some useful charts that you can generate. Highly recommend this as a tool; as a bonus, it's free

Comment: I recommend the lens but it would be very unusual for any patent search engine to not allow this distinction. Google patent search advanced has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen a search engine without the ability to filter on granted vs application. However the way to do that did not jump out at me at DEPATIS. Looks like you might to use Kind Codes. (also your link to it has a typo).

At google patents advanced https://patents.google.com/advanced  you enter info and check boxes on the left side. It produces a search string like -

> assignee:IBM country:DE status:GRANT

Comment: Fixed the typo, thanks!

Comment: It up to you but you can accept an answer if you chose and it will prevent it from automatically coming up to the top over and over periodically. You might get a better answer that addresses the German site. I do not need the points.

Comment: do you happen to know if Google Patents is reasonably up to date on German patents, e.g. would have granted patent info within a couple months of the German patent office granting it?

Comment: I would guess so but don’t have any experience to back it up.